# PHP error_reporting issue, even local = On

Tags: php, ini-set

in my php.ini the display_errors setting is set to Off by standard. Usually I started my index.php file with

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

which all worked fine for my needs.

Recently, the error reporting did not work anymore. notices have been thrown out though, so:

```
<?php echo $i ?>
```

throws a notice "undefined constant"

```
<?php badbadbad ?>
```

simply returns a blank page instead of a Fatal Error message.

Checking phpinfo() shows that the Master value for display_errors is Off, while the local value is set to On (as expected). Nevertheless I could not get any error message.

Changing my php.ini setting for display_errors = On gets me around this issue, but should not be a solution for ever.

Any hints?

Thanks & brgds
David

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason your second example fails is that it's actually a Parse Error.

When executing code, PHP has to first parse and compile the whole file it's going to execute and then only after that it can run it. If there's a problem during parsing, even if the problem is at the end of the file, none of the file's code will be executed -- so neither will your `ini_set()` and `error_reporting()` statements.

If the erroneous code is in the same file as said statements, there's not much you can do. If it's in another file that is used with `include` or `require`, make sure that the including calls are made *after* setting the new error reporting values. At least that works for me with PHP >= 5.4.